# jQuery update data attr for element

Tags: html, jquery

So I have list of items and I need to add "data-index" for each element, index for first three elements have to be 3, for next 3 elements index have to be 6 ...

Should be something like this

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item" data-index="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="3"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="3"></div>

    <div class="item" data-index="6"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="6"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="6"></div>

    <div class="item" data-index="9"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="9"></div>
    <div class="item" data-index="9"></div>
</div>
```

Anyone have idea how to do it ?

I have this code which add numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('data-index',e)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
  var index = 3 * Math.floor(i / 3) + 3;
  $(this).attr('data-index', index);
});
```